# Why Stellar has totalCoins in every ledger header?

Tags: ledger, inflation, xdr

I'm looking at the xdr definition of the `LedgerHeader` structure and it has the `totalCoin` fields -- so, why does every ledger header need to have `totalCoins` recorded in it?

How would that value ever change?

Answer (score 2):

Total number of all XLM is not a constant. Every week the built-in inflation mechanism distributes new lumens. You can find detailed information [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/inflation.html).

Comment: Thanks! So the inflation coins are created each week from scratch? Not redistributed?

Comment: Inflation distributes fees from the `fee_pool` and creates a portion of new coins to keep a steady total supply growth (1% yearly).

Comment: Thanks! Do I understand correctly how inflation is carried out: each week, nodes carry out a calculation for each account in the ledger which has non-zero inflation destination votes, which distributes newly created lumens + lumens in the fee pool to those accounts which have more than MIN_VOTE votes, in proportion to how many lumens they have. Nodes do this independently and the result is published as an inflation operation. This operation is then accepted in the usual way by consensus?

Comment: Yeah. Min vote is **0.05%** of all existing coins. Regular accounts with balance less than `min_vote` can also vote for the inflation pools (like https://pool.lumenaut.net/), which regularly distribute inflation rewards. The `inflation` operation can be submitted by any account, and the consensus for this operation type works as usual.